# NetSuite SuiteScript Reference Key not being recognized

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I am trying to get a script to set a field in a Purchase Order after processing a Sales Order. The field is 'department' and the reference key is 71. However, I am getting the error: "Invalid department reference key 71 for subsidiary "

The code is simple enough:

```
obj_New_PO.setFieldValue('department', 71);
```

I am fairly new to NetSuite scripting so I am not sure on this error. I checked the reference keys for 'department' (under Setup -> Company -> Departments) and 71 does exist.

Any ideas as to why the Purchase Order is not seeing the correct reference key?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Departments are restricted to specific Subsidiaries. You will need to make sure that the Department in question is available in the PO's Subsidiary. Just view the *Subsidiaries* field on the Department record.

Comment: Thank you. I am trying to figure out the correlation between the two. I am not seeing why these fields are causing the error because as far as I can tell, everything lines up correctly.

Comment: Are you explicitly setting `subsidiary` on `obj_New_PO`? If you are creating `obj_New_PO` in Dynamic mode, you will need to set `subsidiary` before you set `department` (and before most other fields). If  you're creating it in Standard mode, you just need to make sure you are setting `subsidiary` on `obj_New_PO` at some point.

Comment: I tried that with no success. I thought that to be the case as well so I tried setting it first. No joy.  I received the Invalid subsidiary reference key 1 for entity. <NULL>

I will continue debugging this. Any other thoughts would be greatly appreciated though.

Comment: So I looked at the code again and moved setting the Entity field above setting the department and it seems to have fixed the issue. So, explicitly setting the Entity field fixed the department setting. It was not Subsidiary, but Entity. Thank you all for your input!